# Voltage input values for Si550 voltage controlled oscillator?

Tags: oscillator

I am trying to find the required voltage input for a particular  Mhz frequency output, I chose a voltage controlled oscillator to allow for user over/under clocking.

Datasheet, I probably missed something...

```
https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/Si550.pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're missing something. There's a nominal frequency, depending on which Si550  device you order, and a Frequency/control voltage slope. See page 10 for the nominal frequency, see table 2 on page 2 for the Control Voltage Tuning slope.